# How to import movie database to mysql

Tags: mysql

I am working on a little project ,i would like to import  The Plain Text Data Files from imdb to mysql .

ftp://ftp.fu-berlin.de/pub/misc/movies/database/

Also i want to know if is legal to use it on a comercial app ?

Thank you guys.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is too broad in scope, and because it asks for legal advice.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [IMDB data usage guidelines](http://www.imdb.com/help/show_leaf?usedatasoftware), you are not allowed to use their data to create a database, online or offline, and you are not allowed to use it in a commercial app. Sorry!

Answer (score 2):

Check out http://imdbpy.sourceforge.net/

That project includes a script to convert the data into a form you can load into an SQL database. http://imdbpy.sourceforge.net/docs/README.sqldb.txt

And no, as @TobyRush answered, you're not allowed to use the IMDB data for commercial applications, according to their terms of usage.

If you need to clarify their license, you should contact IMDB.